# How to achieve Local Notification in android 2.3.1?

Tags: android

any one know how to achieve local notification in android.currently i am working on Android2.3.1  please help to achieve it....

Thanks in Advance---

Comment: Do you want to send a broadcast notification?  Or just raise a small message that notifies the user of something?

Comment: Whether you want to Push Notification?

Comment: @phobos i just want to show message box on current application screen,on which i want to put buttons afterwards.,so please suggest..

Comment: @venkatesh nopes no push notification bcz push notification occurs at the corner side of screen,i want at middle of screen..

Comment: I think its not possible to display at center..

Comment: same question asked by user multiple number of times

Comment: @Smith please don't ask the same question over and over.  You have asked several different closely related questions about this recently.  This may lead to your questions being closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I seems from your comment that you are looking for a Dialog not a notification. This code will give you a dialog with a yes and no button.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Put your question here?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // put your code here
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // put your code here 
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```